# Why is /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default returning blank?

Tags: apache, lamp, ubuntu-14.04

I installed LAMP and phpmyadmin in my server. (Droplet in DigitalOcean)

I have problem in editing the file here
`sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`

This returns an empty file.

I even tried 
`sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default`
and it is also empty.

When I tried

```
> ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled


    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Nov 14  2013 000-default -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf
```

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This did the work for me.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Also edited the vhost with the following to enable `.htaccess`.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```